# Lombok with Generics Failing in Maven

Tags: java, maven, generics, lombok

My maven build was failing with the following error caused by a particular class:

> cannot find symbol static of

...and a load of other similar errors because Lombok annotation processing seems to stop as soon as it hits this. This is the code, on which it breaks:

```java
@AllArgsConstructor(staticName = "of")
public class TestCase<T, U> {
    public final T input;
    public final U expected;
}
```

I have this issue using Java 8 or Java 9 and Maven 3.5.2.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is an issue with the **Lombok named attributes on annotations combined with generics** used in this class (as I have lots of other classes with similar Lombok annotations that work fine. Manually partially delombokking the code as below caused the build to work:

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TestCase<T, U> {
  public final T input;
  public final U expected;

  public static <T,U> TestCase<T,U> of(T input, U expected) {
    return new TestCase<T, U>(input, expected);
  }
}
```